# Is there an AppCompat equivalent of Widget.Material.Spinner.Underlined?

Tags: android, spinner, android-appcompat

Is it possible to get the equivalent style of Widget.Material.Spinner.Underlined using the AppCompat libraries for pre v21 devices?

I want to support v16+ in my app, but would really like to get the underline effect on Spinners using the AppCompat libraries if possible.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. It seems if i have to support my app in 16+ android then i will have to be content with a spinner without an underline then.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

UPDATE (March 11, 2015): AppCompat revision 22 introduced a Spinner style that includes the underline: "Base.Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined" (http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html#revisions)

OLD ANSWER: AppCompat does not have an equivalent, you'll have to figure add the underline yourself.

There is an issue about this, which was marked as being fixed in a "Future release." There have been several AppCompat releases since then, but still no sign of an Underline style.

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77819

Answer (score 19):

For anybody who needs the code to get this working.
Just make sure you're using rev22 of the AppCompat v7 library and then put the following in your style.xml file:

```
<item name="MySpinnerStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined</item>
```

Also make sure to change `MySpinnerStyle` to be the name of your style you set your spinner to.
Here is where I got my answer (credit goes to jkane001!)
[code.android.com: Appcompat: missing Spinner.Underline style](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=77819)

Comment: hey @meandnotyou , you may want to check out this answer if you are having trouble getitng it working, I believe you may need this line of code :-)

Comment: How can we change the color of the arrow and this underline as per color primary and color accent? `colorControlHighlight` is working proper, but I want a default state!

Comment: Found it: `<item name="android:colorControlNormal">@color/myControlColor</item>` Sexy is just a word!

Comment: Any way to remove the drop down arrow and have it underlined ? if I set any background, the underline disappears

Answer (score 2):

```
<item name="android:spinnerStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined</item> 
<item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/your_color</item>
```

After adding second line, I got underline on my kitkat device too.

Answer (score -2):

Use a style for the spinner, for example this:

style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner"